# Can't reshape and populate Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack, multi-index

I have a dataframe of counts that I would like to restructure to a multiindex form. I can get the structure of the multi index dataframe properly.  But I'm unable to populate the new dataframe.
Here is the starting data frame. The dataframe is named counts.

```
resp_gender female  male    All
Q19         
_1  602.0   238.0   840.0
_10 532.0   155.0   687.0
_2  54.0    31.0    85.0
_3  66.0    29.0    95.0
_4  41.0    27.0    68.0
_5  67.0    43.0    110.0
_6  108.0   57.0    165.0
_7  104.0   56.0    160.0
_8  209.0   126.0   335.0
_9  213.0   114.0   327.0
All 1996.0  876.0   2872.0
```

I have the following program that puts the dataframe into the right structure.  But does not populate the cells.

Here is my program.

```
iterables = [['_1', '_2', '_3', '_4','_5','_6','_7','_8','_9','_10','All'], 
             ['Counts']]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables,
        names=['Table Results', 'Type'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=counts,index=index,columns=['male','female','ALL'])
```

Here is the output

```
        male    female  ALL
Table Results   Type            
_1  Counts  NaN NaN NaN
_2  Counts  NaN NaN NaN
_3  Counts  NaN NaN NaN
_4  Counts  NaN NaN NaN
_5  Counts  NaN NaN NaN
_6  Counts  NaN NaN NaN
_7  Counts  NaN NaN NaN
_8  Counts  NaN NaN NaN
_9  Counts  NaN NaN NaN
_10 Counts  NaN NaN NaN
All Counts  NaN NaN NaN
```

As you can see the structure is correct.  But the columns aren't populated with data.

What am I missing?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(data=count.values,index=index,columns=['male','female','ALL'])` add values

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.